# how to merge product image and meta in single div in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

i'm working on a woocommerce based site in wordpress. i'm using the the-bootstrap theme and woocommerce Version 2.1.12. i'm on single product page and the design of my page is like:

```
<div class="images">...</div>
<div class="summary entry-summary">...</div>
<div class="product_meta">...</div>
```

Now i want to merge the images div and product meta div in a single div so that i can place another div after summary like this:

```
<div class="span3">
<div class="images">...</div>
<div class="product_meta">...</div>
</div>

<div class="span6 summary entry-summary">...</div>
<div class="span3 Product category">...</div>
```

but its all written as hooks in the woocommerce template.so how can i change this to get the desired output.

Here is the code for my content-single-product template:

```
<?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_before_single_product_summary hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

    <div class="summary entry-summary">

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
        ?>

    </div><!-- .summary -->

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

    <meta itemprop="url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Move `product_meta` into your `_before_single_product_summary` hook
2. Theme the **content-single-product.php** template by wrapping the `_before_single_product_summary` action in `div` tags.

Please see the [documentation on overriding templates](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) for more information, concerning step #2.

Comment: :i have updated my question with content-single-product code.i dont know about hooks so can u please tell me where i have to change in my file.

Comment: Here's the relevant [WooCommerce Hooks & Filters Documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/).